# Con respecto a los metodos

Tags: java

¿Para que me sirven los métodos con retorno de valores(return) y los métodos vacíos (void)? ¿Cual es la utilidad de cada uno?

Comment: Estás preguntando sobre que hace cada método? O por algún caso tuyo específico que tengas?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html ahi tienes, a estudiar!

Answer (score 3):

Esto deberías mirarlo en la [documentación de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html), pero te voy a hacer un breve resumen.

Los métodos `void` no retornan nada, es decir, hacen acciones dentro, o modifican valores o alteran el funcionamiento del programa pero no te devuelven ni valores ni nada. es decir:

```
private void suma(){
  int x=1;
  int i=2;
  int z= x + i;
}
```

Esta función hace una suma que no va a salir de este método (Este método no tiene ninguna utilidad, es solo un ejemplo). 
En cambio, si queremos que nos devuelva un valor haríamos algo así:

```
private int suma(){
      int x=1;
  int i=2;
  int z= x + i;
  return z;
}
```

De esta forma, desde fuera podríamos obtener **z** de la siguiente manera:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    int suma = suma();//Suma será 3
 }
```

En resumen, si quieres obtener cualquier tipo de valor de una función, debes retornar un valor. Una posible utilidad es la de comparar dos valores:

```
private boolean sonIguales(int i, int j){
   boolean b=false;
   if(i==j){


      b=true;
}
return b;
}

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    if(sonIguales(1,1)){
     //hacer cosas
   }
 }
```